# SyntaxError: Missing semicolon when trying to Use an External Editor in the mongo Shell

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to [Use an External Editor in the mongo Shell](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/configure-mongo-shell/#use-an-external-editor-in-the-mongo-shell), as explained in mongodb documentation.

So I am doing as follow:

`export EDITOR=vim`

`mongosh mongodb+srv://devcluster.br7xj.aws.mongodb.net/jdoe -u john-doe -p password`

and then in mongo shell I type `edit something` and looking forward to see it on my vim. But I get...

```
Uncaught:
SyntaxError: Missing semicolon. (1:4)

> 1 | edit something
    |     ^
  2 |
```

How can I resolve it, and open it on my vim editor?

Comment: I see the same behavior, but it works with legacy mongo shell, not sure what the diffirence

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per comment by user "dododo", use the mongo command, not the mongosh command...

```
export EDITOR=vim

mongo mongodb+srv://devcluster.br7xj.aws.mongodb.net/jdoe -u john-doe -p password
```

Comment: Thank you so much guys.
You were so helpful